# Spring MVC&ThymeLeaf: th:text doesn't show controller's provided content

Tags: html, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I've following problem:

My controller uses a Hibernate DAO to fetch data from a database. Now, I want to display that data on a website. The fetching works fine, but somehow the fetched data isn't displayed in "th:text" field.

Here is the critical part in html file:

```
<div class="item active"
                                    th:each="article : ${getAllArticles}">
                                    <div class="carousel-content">
                                        <div>
                                        <!-- Controller generated header -->
                                            <h3 class="article_header" th:text="${hp_header}"></h3>
                                            <p>
                                                <small>Android, EU, Google</small>
                                            </p>
                                            <p th:text="${hp_content}">Lorem ipsum dolor
                                                sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                                                eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
                                                erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                                                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
                                                takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                            <div class="button_area">
                                                <a class="btn btn-large btn-info" href="detailview.html">
                                                    Details </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END ITEM  -->
```

And here is the associated controller class:

```
@Controller
```

public class IndexController {

```
private Article prioArticle;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    fetchHighPrioContent();
    model.addAttribute("hp_header", prioArticle.getHeadLine());
    System.out.println(prioArticle.getHeadLine());
    model.addAttribute("hp_content", prioArticle.getContent());
    System.out.println(prioArticle.getContent());
    return "index";
}


private void fetchHighPrioContent(){
    //get highest rated article
    prioArticle = ArticleHandler.getInstance().retriveByRank(1).get(0);
    System.out.println("DEBUG: " + prioArticle.getArtID() + " " + prioArticle.getHeadLine());
}
```

}

Comment: For starters your controller is flawed (try to think about 10 requests coming in and what would the value of `prioArticle` be? Next there is no `getAllArticles` added to the model so there is nothing to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the article from your for each before the attribute?

Something like.... th:text="${article.hp_content}"
And like this..... th:text="${article.hp_header}"

Check it out in [enter link description here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html) You have an example under : 8.4 Removing template fragments